# SQL query for Ms Access database. To query access database from similar id group

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, subquery, ms-access-2010

Below is my table structure in ms access ,

| ID | Stage_Name | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 07:00 |
| 1 | B | 08:00 |
| 1 | C | 09:00 |
| 2 | A | 08:00 |
| 2 | B | 09:00 |
| 3 | A | 07:00 |

The output should retrieve any records that have not went through stage B yet. Output will be,

| ID | Stage_Name | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | A | 07:00 |

kindly please help me

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really a place to ask people to do the work for you. Instead, try showing what you've already tried, what things you've encountered and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                         t2.stage_name = 'B'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` and a correlated subquery for filtering. The idea is to ensure that there is no earlier record in stage B for the same id:

```
select t.*
from mytable as t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable as t1 
    where t1.id = t.id and t1.stage_name = 'B' and t1.time < t.time
)
```

This matches your description of your question (*records that have not went through stage B **yet***) but not your desired results.

If you want to exclude records whose id has any B, even later on, you can just remove condition `t1.time < t.time` from the subquery.